# Disable auto focus to console when snippet runs

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

In Chrome Developer Tools, in the source tab when you run snippets with the Run button or Ctrl+Enter, devtools does auto focus to the console tab, so I cannot continue to do coding on the source tab efficiently. I googled about the solution and took a look the devtools preference but couldn't find a good resource. Thanks.